# Determining if string is palindrome

Tags: python

I wrote two simple functions to determine if a string is a palindrome. I thought they were equivalent, but 2 doesn't work. Why is this?

**1**

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    if string == string[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**2**

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    if string == reversed(string):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: A simple hint for code conciseness: you can simply return the comparison value (i.e. `return string == string[::-1]`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`reversed` doesn't create a string but a 'reversed' object:

```
>>> reversed('radar')
<reversed object at 0x1102f99d0>
```

As such, the string `'radar'` does not compare equal to the object `reversed('radar')`. To make it work, you need to make sure the `reversed` object is actually evaluated:

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    if string == u''.join(reversed(string)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The `u''.join(reversed(string))` inserts `u''` in between each of the characters in the string and this leads to the reversed string being turned into a string object.

Answer (score 1):

In the second one, you need to make a `str` from the `reversed` type instance -- it's not hard:

```
if string == ''.join(reversed(string)):
```

Answer (score 0):

For strings:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    """Return True if a string is a palindrome."""
    return s == s[::-1]
```

For general iterables (including strings):

```
def is_palindrome(iterable):
    """Return True if an iterable is a palindrome."""
    if list(iteable) == list(reversed(iterable))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = input("Enter a string")
print("\n".join(["Inserted string is" + "NOT"*((str[::-1])!=str)+ " a palindrome"]))
```

Comment: This is a bad answer! it does not satisfy the question!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.